# Zabbix strange situation on Latest Data

Tags: linux, zabbix

Below I attach screen on zabbix:

[image]

Anybody have some idea why in Latest Data I see information about Items? No settings have not been changed Zabbix. This situation are only for me account. On different account everything it's o.k.

Please give me some advice.

Regards
Mick

Comment: Could you please describe what do you find strange about the screenshot? If you are wondering why you are seeing only a particular subset of items, you might have filter enabled. In order to see it, expand the "Filter" strip (it can be seen in the middle of the screenshot).

Comment: O.k thx for help, my mistake :/.. I turned on the filter (Show details)